# What is the house upgrade order in Animal Crossing: New Horizons

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I play Animal Crossing: New Horizons and I'm wondering what the house upgrading order because I want to know what's next in the housing upgrades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First House Upgrade:

- 98,000 bells to upgrade to this house
- You change from a tent to a house
- You just get one room
- The dimensions are 6x6 squares (36 in total)

Second House Upgrade:

- 198,000 bells to upgrade to this house
- You get a larger room
- You just get a one large room
- The dimensions are 8x8 (64 in total)
- You get +28 squares
- You get +40 storage (total: 120)

First Room Expansion:

- 348,000 bells to upgrade to this house
- You get an extra room to the back of your house
- You have two rooms
- The dimensions of this room is 6x6 (36 in total)
- You get +36 squares
- You get +120 storage (total: 240)

Second Room Expansion:

- 548,000 bells to upgrade to this house
- You get an extra room to the left of your house
- You have three rooms
- The dimensions of this room is 6x6 (36 in total)
- You get +36 squares
- You get +80 storage space (total: 320)
- You can move your mailbox

Third Room Expansion:

- 758,000 bells to upgrade to this house
- You get an extra room to the right of your house
- You have 4 rooms
- The dimensions are 6x6 (36 in total)
- You get +36 squares
- You get +80 storage space (total: 400)

Second Floor Expansion:

- 1,248,000 bells to upgrade to this house
- You get a second floor (to access, go to the front of your house and go up the staircase)
- You have 5 rooms
- The dimensions are 6x10 squares (60 in total)
- You get +60 squares
- You get +400 storage space (total:800)

Basement Expansion:

- 2,498,000 bells to upgrade to this house
- You get a basement (to access this room, go to the stairs across from your upstairs)
- You have 6 rooms
- The dimensions are 6x10 squares (60 in total)
- You get +60 squares
- You get +800 storage space (1,600 total)
- After paying this loan, you can customize you house (exterior) for free

Storage Expansion:

- 500,000 bells to upgrade to this house
- You get +800 storage space (2,400 total)

Thats pretty much it